# Why $N_G(E)/C_G(E)$ has order prime to $p$ where $E$ is a rank 1 elementary $p$ subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group, with $p$-rank 1. i.e. the largest rank of elementary $p$ sub groups is 1, why $N_G(E)/C_G(E)$ has order prime to $p$ where $E$ is a rank 1 elementary $p$ subgroup of $G$?

Thanks!

Comment: @Crostul, thanks for pointing out the typo. I have edited it.

Comment: What is an elementary $p$-subgroup?

Comment: By the way, I have no idea on how to prove this result. Maybe you should first try to prove it first for finite groups.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft, a group is an elementary p-group if it is iso to $(Z/pZ)^n$.

Comment: Usually, that is called an elementary abelian $p$-group. And in this case, your question is fairly trivial, by the normalizer/centralizer theorem.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft, you are right. Thanks for your answer.